# total number of totally odd digits less than $100000000$ if totally odd number is composed of digits $1$,$3$,$5$,$7$,$9$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A totally odd number is a number composed of digits {$1$,$3$,$5$,$7$,$9$ } .
Eg 133 is a totally odd number as it is composed of 1 and 3 but 130 is not a totally odd number .

What are the total number of totally odd numbers less than $100000000$?
I came across the solution to the problem on  and it says 
         5^1+5^2+....+5^8 but couldn't understand as how this solution is correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Each digit can be one of 5 digits.  So there are $5^k$ $k$- digit totally odd numbers.

So $N = \sum_{k=1}^8 5^k$.

$N+1 = 1 + 5 + 5^2 + ..... + 5^8 = \frac {5^9 - 1}{5-1}$

So there are $\frac{5^9 -1}4 - 1=488280$ totally odd numbers less than $10^8$

Comment: so there are 5^k k digit odd numbers .can you explain this more clearly as how ?

Comment: Sure.  You have 5 chooses for the first digit.  And for each of those you have 5 chooses of the second digit.  And for each of those five sets of five chooses you have five chooses for the third digit.  And so on.  So how many choices total to you have for k digits?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want to count the number of strings of lengths from-one-to-eight where each digit must be one of five options, $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$, with repetition allowed.

---

Today's Hint is: *Geometric Series*.

---

After the OP edit:

> I came across the solution to the problem on and it says 5^1+5^2+....+5^8 but couldn't understand as how this solution is correct ?

$5^k$ is the counts of ways to make $k$ choices each with 5 independent options.  Such as forming a string of length $k$ from the five digits with repletion.

So $\sum_{k=1}^8 5^k$ is the count of ways to do so for strings of lengths from 1 through to 8.   As hinted, a geometric series is involved.

$$\sum_{k=1}^8 5^8 ~=~ 5+5^2+\cdots+5^8 ~=~ \dfrac{5(5^8-1)}{5-1}$$

Comment: the solution says 5^1+5^2+5^3+.....+5^8

Comment: @which is what you'd expect it to be, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, that is *a* geometric series: and can you see what how to get it?

Comment: It's a geometric series but it is missing the first $5^0 = 1$ summand.  As the sum of the geometric series $1 + a + a^2 + ...... + a^k = \frac{a^{k+1} - 1}{a -1}$ we can readily solve this.

Comment: Missing the first summand, or multiplied by 5, depending on your point of view.  $$\color{grey}{\sum_{k=1}^n r^k = \dfrac{r(r^k-1)}{r-1}}$$

Comment: Oh, multiplied by five.... didn't think of it that way.  $a + a^2 + .... + a^{k+1} = a(1 + ... + a^k) = a\frac{a^{k+1} - 1}{a-1}::a+a^2 + .... + a^{k+1} = (1 + ... +a^{k+1}) - 1 = \frac{a^{k+1} - 1}{a-1} - 1$.  Interesting.